# background not moving in pygame

Tags: pygame

So I tried to write a code to make my map, an 800 x 8000 image, move upwards. but for some reason the image doesn't show up. i tried to find out what's wrong in my code, but i just cant seem to figure it out. here's the code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("RUN!")
icon = pygame.image.load('running-icon-png-26.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# map
mapimg = pygame.image.load('map2.png')
mapimgX = 800
mapimgY = 8000



# gameloop
running = True
while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
screen.blit(mapimg, (800, mapimgY))

mapimgY -= 1

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Things that happen in the game loop need to be indented inside the gameloop.

```py
# gameloop
running = True
while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
     
     # ---> INDENTATION
     screen.blit(mapimg, (800, mapimgY))

     mapimgY -= 1

     pygame.display.update()
     clock.tick(60)
```

Also keep in mind that if you set your coordinates to `(800, 8000)`, you will see nothing. Pygame images are placed at their top left corner, and the top left corner of the screen is `(0, 0)`. So y coordinates go up as you go down the screen. It may seem confusing but you'll get the hang of it.

To start, try placing your image at `(0,0)`, that way you will definitely see it.

Also, if you call `.convert()` on your mapimg, like `mapimg = pygame.image.load('map2.png').convert()`, you will likely see a large performance improvement.